# How to pass a string as an argument in python without "namespace"

Tags: python, argparse

How do you pass a string as an argument in python without the output containing "Namespace".

Here is my code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("person", help="person to test",type=str)
person = str(parser.parse_args())
print "The person's name is " + person
```

Here is the command I am running:

```
python test.py bob
```

This is my output:

```
The person's name is Namespace(person='bob')
```

I could probably do some fancy splitting,  but I'm sure I'm just leveraging the argparse incorrectly(I'm new to python) if anyone can please tell me how to properly pass a string like this I would greatly apreciate it.

Comment: Why not use `sys.argv[1]` instead?

Comment: Maybe go through the first little bit of the [argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)

Comment: There is an awesome library for this called click, check it out http://click.pocoo.org/5/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The namespace is a container for the results of argument parsing. You can access the individual argument values by looking them up in the namespace:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("person", help="person to test",type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
print "The person's name is " + args.person
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html) have some great examples that show how to use argparse.

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm, and your explanation makes perfect sense